# Certain file types do not upload using Zend.to

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, file-upload, mime-types

I have been heavily editting Zend.to to fit my needs and have realized that when I upload certain file formats (.docx, .xlsx, .pptx), the file is not written to the database. I have been scouring the code for hours looking for the source of this problem and am fairly sure it is due to the mimeType of these files, but I cannot figure out what setting/file is causing this. I thought I'd ask here to see if there was something simple I may have been missing.

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to save the file in the DB or in a folder?, can you put some code?

Comment: The file is being written to a folder.

Comment: I could post code, but I would not be positive if the code I posted was even the source of the problem.

Comment: Are you able to upload these files through anything else, for instance GMail?

Comment: Just something you might want to check, do you get the extension of the file somewhere in your code ?  You might be checking the last three characters only of the extension and it might cause a glitch somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the code working with the fileinfo extension doesn't like that xml document. We created a workaround where all files uploaded are application/octet-stream instead of their appropriate file.

In version 4.08 lines 1537-1542 of the .\lib\nssdropoff.php we forced all file types to application/octet-stream:

```
            if ( ! $this->_dropbox->database->DBAddFile1($dropoffID, $tmpname,
                         stripslashes($_FILES[$key]['name']),
                         $bytes,
                        "application/octet-stream",
                         stripslashes($_POST["desc_".$i])) ) {
```

We are merging our fix with 4.10 now and will in two weeks be uploaded all of our fixes (and a customized styled to match our needs) to the Zend.to project for Jules review. Our biggest issue was getting the entire setup working perfectly on IIS w/php and a working progress bar.